# Can I ask about topics regarding elderly parents and taking legal control of their finances and assets?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

It's certainly no unusual thing that parents age and sometimes need special care in their final years. One such situation is they can no longer manage their finances and assets appropriately, leaving the children to keep their parents from falling into unmanageable debt and foreclosures. To what extent can I ask questions regarding this process, whereby a child takes legal control of a parent's finances and assets before their death? My concerns would mostly be where the legal ramifications begin and end, and where the financial ramifications take over.  It seems clear that the law is off topic comment but there also seems to be overlap.

Answer (score 2):

My view is that in general it's ok to ask questions about the mechanics of taking over finances, e.g. how to get banks to let you do it or how to manage the money.

Probably too far towards the legal end would be a legal dispute about whether you can take over someone's finances.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, given the high level overview, this can't be answered yes/no.

I cam easily contrive a few questions that are clearly off topic, legal, and would be migrated, a few that are so on topic, I'm surprised they haven't been asked already, and some gray.

I'd suggest you write the question, and give it a once-over. No secret that you've answered 4 question all voted up, and just one of 4 questions asked voted net down.  <del>Worst case is a legal question might get migrated.</del> Worst case is that a good question goes unasked.